# Issue with Laravel Symbolic Links

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, storage

I have specific folder for each user inside `storage/app/public`.
I'm dynamically changing the public_path as:

```
$storageConfig = Config::get('filesystems.disks.public');
$storageConfig['root'] = storage_path('app/public/').$userString ;
config()->set('filesystems.disks.public', $storageConfig);
```

When a user uploads his photo, it will get saved in the path

```
storage/app/public/$userString/profile_pictures
```

I used the php artisan command to create the link:

```
php artisan storage: link
```

But I have this issue while displaying images.
Using symbolic link, images are displayed as:

```
  <img src="{{asset('storage/').$profilepicture}}">
```

Images are not loading . What can be the issue? Can someone help?

Comment: What if you do this: `<img src="{{asset('storage/'.$profilepicture)}}">`

Comment: @Ahsan this is not working

Comment: Are you changing the path in a middleware?

Comment: @SérgioReis yes

Comment: In your .blade what does it output if you try this `{{Storage::disk("public")->getDriver()->getAdapter()->getPathPrefix()}}`

Comment: @SérgioReis it points to the user folder :storage/app/public/$userString/

Answer (score 0):

To call images from storage you should use the built in helper:

e.g.

```
<img src="{{ Storage::url($userString. '/profile_pictures/' .$profilepicture) }}">
```

[see here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/filesystem#retrieving-files)

This will work after having used `php artisan storage:link`

Comment: updated, is the link correct in the source generated?